# ERROR in node_modules/apollo-angular/Apollo.d.ts(26,17)

Tags: angular7, azure-pipelines, node-modules, apollo-client, apollo-angular

I am working on Angular 7 project and the application is deployed in Azure App Services and Pipeline for the same in on Azure DevOps. It is basically CI/CD. Everything was fine, branch code merging (Code Integration) and deployment (Code Deployment - pipeline) but suddenly I am getting *ERROR in node_modules/apollo-angular/Apollo.d.ts(26,17): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context* this error. 
Could somebody help me here to understand and solve the issue?

**Apollo Angular version - 1.3.0**

[image: Versions]

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same error.
I was using apollo-angular@1.9.0.

my way was like this

```
npm uninstall apollo-angular 
npm install apollo-angular@1.8.0
```

i just got the minor version of apollo-angular down

Comment: Thanks Yoseph, but I am using 1.3.0 version of apollo-angular.

Comment: @Hugh No, locally code is building and running properly.